# How to change path of a package in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I installed a new version of Apache server, I used options like `--with-PACKAGE` to configure Apache to use a custom path for a package, but Apache is already installed. How can I change the path of a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing this with `./configure` is like so:

```
./configure ... --with-PACKAGE=<folder>
```

For example:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local
```

If your package has just moved to another location (i.e. it's no longer in its old location), just restarting Apache will do that. If it doesn't, inspect the output of `ldd`:

```
ldd /path/to/httpd
```

Sometimes `/usr/local/lib` is not enabled by default for the linker; you can add this to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` - depending on your preference. Afterwards you have to run `lconfig` to commit the changes.

Comment: As I told I used this way to configure Apache server, should I compile and install it again to change a path for a package?

Comment: @Mjbmr on second read ... did the package just move or did it change version as well?

Comment: @Mjbmr updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Well, Thanks, but I installed openssl somewhere else (like my home directory) and system has it too, I forgot to use --with-ssl=$HOME when I was about to install Apache server, now what should I do? your update wasn't useful for me.

Comment: @Mjbmr what *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? are you trying to upgrade openssl, change openssl ... nothing related to openssl? I'm confused

Comment: First thanks for spending time on it, I installed Apache server in $HOME, I used this way to config it `./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-apr=$HOME --with-apr-util=$HOME --with-neon=$HOME --with-pcre=$HOME` , I forgot to use `--with-ssl=$HOME` so Apache server uses default openssl, I wanna change it to don't use default one.

Comment: @Mjbmr oh okay, then you need to recompile I'm afraid :)